# How to handle printing invoice on given paper. 20 items/sheets and if exceed limit it should go to next page. Total amount on final page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var j = 23;

    for (var i = 0; i < j+11; i++) {
        if (i != 0 && i % 11 == 0) {
            $("#printSection div").append("<?php echo '<tr><td>fff</td></tr>'; ?>");
            $("#printSection div").append("<table><tbody></tbody></table>");
            // alert(j);
            if((j%11)>0){
                var k = j%11;
                var l = 11-k;
                for(var m=0; m<10; m++){
                    $("#printSection div").append("<p>hhh</p>");
                }
            }
        }              

        var node = "<tr><td><?php echo "sdefef"; ?></td><td><?php echo "123"?></td></tr>";
        $("#printSection tbody").last().append(node);

      // alert(i);    
    }
});
```

I want to print MS SQL query output on given paper as a invoice. One paper can have twenty items. If the number of items exceed the 20 it should goes to next page. Like wise finally total amount should displayed on final page only. For example query brings 25 items to be printed on the paper invoice. Total amount is Rs.2000.00. First page should be printed first 20 items only and should go to next page to print other 5 items and final total amount. Same header should be displayed on every invoice page. I wish I could present some images to explain the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
page-break-after: always;
```

You can apply this style in your code.

Comment: Already applied. But this problem is not simple as seems. #printSection table {            
        page-break-after: always;
        page-break-inside: avoid;
        break-inside: avoid;
    }